# is it possible to validate a control in asp.net but not require it?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

Is it possible to validate that it's a phone number but not require it? The way it is right now if I don't enter a number it will throw the error. I read somewhere that you can change the RegEx to do this and I tried by enclosing the RegEx in (?:...?)

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbCompanyFax" Width="99%" Text='<%# Eval("CompanyFax")%>'></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxTK:MaskedEditExtender runat="server" ID="maskCompanyFax" AutoComplete="false" TargetControlID="tbCompanyFax" Mask="(999)999-9999" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regCompanyFax" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbCompanyFax" ErrorMessage="Invalid Fax number" ValidationExpression="(?:((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4})?" Display="None"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: What do you mean with _not require it_? By default a `RegularExpressionValidator` does not validate empty text, hence it is not required.

Comment: @TimSchmelter What I mean is I want to check and make sure there is a valid phone number in the textbox if they do try and enter it - if they don't enter it I'd like to skip validation all together.

Comment: As @TimSchmelter said, this is the default behavior of `RegularExpressionValidator` already.  Are you getting error message "Invalid Fax Number" or something else?  It seems there must be another component involved in the validation.

Comment: FYI, it's "ASP.NET", not "ASP".

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise it seems that I'm submitting the mask and that's why it fails validation. I will have to use a custom validator that will allow the mask - that's my next guess anyway.

Comment: @reds184: Can you try removing the `MaskedEditExtender` and see if you get the expected behavior (leaving the textbox blank is allowed)?  From what I've read, this control should not cause any validation, but maybe it does.

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise I don't think it's the control that does the validation, it's just putting (___)___-____ in the box, when I hit submit - that text goes with it as well. I'm going to try the Regex suggested by nunespascal below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked @nunepascal's RegEx and it works exactly as I wanted.
Thanks again!

```
ValidationExpression="(?:(((\d{3}))|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4})|((((_{3}))|(_{3}-‌​))?_{3}-_{4})"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem arises from the mask being submitted.

You could allow the mask in your RegEx. That would save the trouble of having to write a custom validator.

Try this RegEx

```
(?:((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4})|(((\(\s{3}\) ?)|(\s{3}-))?\s{3}-\s{4})
```

Should make an empty mask valid

Comment: That sounds like the best solution for me at the moment, unfortunately the RegEx is failing if I don't enter a number

Comment: Seems to work for me. [See here](http://www.regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%3F%3A%28%28\%28\d{3}\%29%20%3F%29|%28\d{3}-%29%29%3F\d{3}-\d{4}%29|%28%28%28\%28\s{3}\%29%20%3F%29|%28\s{3}-%29%29%3F\s{3}-\s{4}%29%3F&input=%28123%29123-1234%0A%0A%28999%29999-9999%0A%0A%28%20%20%20%29%20%20%20-%20%20%20%20%0A%0A%28888%29888-8888%0A%0A%28abc%29123-4567%0A%0A%28123%29%20%201-1234%0A%0A%0A)

Comment: I think the Regex you posted allows for whitespace (I don't know regex well at all). I popped yours into Expresso and tweaked it a little. Here is what I came up with.

ValidationExpression="(?:((\(\d{3}\))|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4})|(((\(_{3}\))|(_{3}-))?_{3}-_{4})"

This one works. Couldn't have done it without you, thanks a bunch man!